# How to achieve clickstream or click tracker function in Django?

Tags: ajax, django

I have a question that i want to add the function to track the click stream of user in my website, How can I achieve this, using ajax tracker or Django-tracker modules?

Answer (score 3):

I have actually wrote a django-clickstream application, I just haven't open sourced it yet, I want to test it out to make sure it works well before releasing it.

Here are the steps you need to do to reproduce what I did, it isn't too hard.

First off you would need to keep track of each visitor for the life of their session or cookie. You can do this using django-visitor or roll your own.

Once you have a visitor you can create a custom middleware that will look at each request and then log what url each visitor visits to a database table. Then all you need to do is create a simple web page where you can view the different click streams by visitor.

One important thing to note is that you will need to setup an exclude filter so that the middleware doesn't pick up any urls that you don't want to track (static, etc), I did this with a simple list of regular expressions that I stored in the settings file. If the url doesn't match one of the regular expressions then log it.

The table will get pretty big real fast if you have a popular website so you will need to create a management command to clean out the old records from your tables.

Django-visitor: https://bitbucket.org/kencochrane/django-visitor

**Edit**:

Check out Django-clickstream: https://bitbucket.org/kencochrane/django-clickstream